# Missing content on author archive page

Tags: archives, author, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, author-template

I got problem when I deal with the 'author archives' pages. Initially I used default 'archives.php' from my theme. Then I add a 'author.php' page, tested on my local machine, it was ok to show the archives. After I uploaded the file to my server, the content just can't show up.

I have installed Yoast SEO plugin and I knew it offers a 'disable author archives' function. I'm sure I've unchecked it. The code itself could fetch the right author name in the title of author archive page, while the content are gone. So I can't

To those who may concern, here's the archive page of my site: http://www.hi-check.com/author/daboa/

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
I used code:

```
    <div class="panel callout radius">
    <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), '96' ); ?>
    <div class="right">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta( 'twitter' ); ?>"                                   target="_blank"><i class="fi-social-twitter size-24"></i></a>&nbsp;
    <a href="<?php the_author_meta( 'facebook' ); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fi-social-facebook size-24"></i></a>&nbsp;
    <a href="mailto:<?php the_author_meta( 'email' ); ?>"><i class="fi-mail size-24"></i></a>
```

Then I found out this function could only be used in single blog page (single.php). So I followed official guide and called a curauth like:

```
    <?php get_header(); 
     global $curauth;
     $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) :                   get_userdata(intval($author));
    ?>
```

Then it worked now. Thanks.